# Problema ao submeter formulário com a tag SELECT, array $_POST vazio

Tags: php, html, formulário, post

Ao submeter o formulário acima, o script PHP acusa erro, dizendo que o índice 'estab' está indefinido. A função 'var_dump' mostra um vetor vazio.

```
    <form action="PHP_scripts/gerarApp.php" method="post" onsubmit="return waiting()">
        <select id="estab" name="estab" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Selecione o estabelecimento</option>
            <?php
            foreach($pdo->query("SELECT numEstabelecimento, nomeEstabelecimento FROM Estabelecimento") as $estab)
                echo '<option value='.$estab['numEstabelecimento'].'>'.htmlentities($estab['nomeEstabelecimento']).'</option>';
            ?>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" id="generateApp" value="Gerar Aplicativo" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
    </form>



<?php
var_dump($_POST);
$numEstab = $_POST['estab'];
?>
```

O curioso é que eu tenho uma outra página com um formulário que contém um campo 'select' e funciona. Não entendo porque neste caso não está funcionando.

Alguém saberia me dizer onde está o erro? Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="PHP_scripts/gerarApp.php" method="post" onsubmit="return waiting()">
    <select id="estab" name="estab" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Selecione o estabelecimento</option>
        <?php
        foreach($pdo->query("SELECT numEstabelecimento, nomeEstabelecimento FROM Estabelecimento") as $estab)
            echo '<option value="'.$estab['numEstabelecimento'].'">'.htmlentities($estab['nomeEstabelecimento']).'</option>';
        ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" id="generateApp" value="Gerar Aplicativo" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
</form>
```